# how to download the video using php script

Tags: php

In my program I want to add a download option to download the currently straming video. I tried this code:

```
$psp = "Tom_20_amp__20Jerry_20race-1.flv";
header("Content-type:application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$psp");
```

But I get this error:

> "C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\Tom_20_amp__20Jerry_20race-1-5.flv" is not a valid FLV file.

the video streaming properly. please guide me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change you're header from :

```
header("Content-type:application/octet-stream");
```

To :

```
header("Content-type: video/flv");
```

Then you can do :

```
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"$psp\"");
//allways a good idea to let the browser know how much data to expect
header("Content-length: " . filesize($psp) . "\n\n"); 
echo file_get_contents($psp); //$psp should contain the full path to the video
```

Comment: thank you so much its working fine but it automattically open the player and streaming the downloaded vedio is it anyother way to stop that

Comment: that depends higly on the browser , for example in FF if i whant to download an mp3 i allways need to click "save linked file" , becouse if i click the link it will start the player like in you're case . then i have to go to file and save file as , when in IE it will start to download automaticly when i click the link . this is how browsers usualy deal with downloads ( i gues you can deactivate this behaviour in you're browser settings , but if a user has this setting on there is no way you can stop it from happening )

Comment: thank you for your fast reply in my application i am downloading all type of videos so if i add header("Content-type: video/flv");
in header part then i download the avi video it rise any  issue or  i should add all header in my code /

Comment: be prepared for all kinds of videos with different headers ( for example avi has different headers from mpg and flv , search stackoverflow , there was a post containing multiple header info for multiple video types ), allso you could try to use header("Content-type: application/force-download"); to force a download instead of play , didn't tested it so i don't know how it works .

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to allow files to be downloaded instead of streamed then something like this should work. You will obviously need to change the paths.

```
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
```

**EDIT**

In your case it will be something like this.

```
// We'll be outputting a video
header('Content-type: video/flv');

// It will be called video.flv
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="video.flv"');

// The PDF source is in original.flv
readfile('original.flv');
```

Comment: sending a flv with pdf headers will get him in the same situation as he is in now .