# How to download a video or audio file from any remote url using php?

Tags: php

I want to download a video / audio file form remote url using php. I had tried the below 
code its work fine. But it takes time to download. How to download in fastest way. And also i want to get the downloaded file size and duration of file. Please help me how to do this.

My code here:

```
<?php
$remote_url = ; // Any remote url with direct file path
$content = get_headers($remote_url,1);
$content = array_change_key_case($content, CASE_LOWER);
if ($content['content-disposition']) {
$tmp_name = explode('=', $content['content-disposition']);
if ($tmp_name[1]) 
$realfilename = trim($tmp_name[1],'";\'');
} else  
{
$stripped_url = preg_replace('/\\?.*/', '', $remote_url);
$realfilename = basename($stripped_url);
} 
$remote_file_contents = file_get_contents($remote_url );
$local_file_path = $realfilename.'';
$song_copied = file_put_contents($local_file_path, $remote_file_contents);
?>
```

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
// We'll be outputting a video
header('Content-type: video/flv');

header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"$psp\"");
//allways a good idea to let the browser know how much data to expect

header("Content-length: " . filesize($psp) . "\n\n"); 

echo file_get_contents($psp); //$psp should contain the full path to the video
```

**Refer:** [how to download the video using php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624012/how-to-download-the-video-using-php-script)