# PHP target_blank implantation

Tags: php

Currently, I have a tiktok downloader project that I've recently started and I came into a little problem where instead opening up a new tab to download the videos, it opens within the same broswer tab. I know html has a `target="blank"` thing but I'm not sure how to add it in a php statement. Any help?

php code

```
<a target="_blank"> <button id="wmarked_link"disabled="disabled" class="download-button" 
   onclick="window.location.href='<?php if ($store_locally){ echo $filename;} else { echo $contentURL; } ?>'">Download Video</button></a>
```

Comment: Don't put a button inside an anchor, it doesn't work in some browsers.

Comment: `target=_blank` only works when you're following the link in the `<a>` tag. If you're using `onclick` JS it's ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove onclick inside a button and move content inside 'window.location.href' of button to <a href='' instead of button

Comment: Okay so I did what you did but now, it opens a new tab but the new tab i wanna open is still occurring on the tab I've just clicked on.
`<a href='<?php if ($store_locally){ echo $filename;} else { echo $contentURL; } ?>' target="_blank"> <button id="wmarked_link"disabled="disabled" class="download-button">Download Video</button></a>` Unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It depend on Content-Type of new tab setting (Backend).
like this
`header("Content-type: video/mp4");`

Comment: I just realized that this php code alone, all that is doing is it's adding to the existing url. For example, www.exmaple.com/downloader/*then this php content filles with random file names". I just don't know how I could fix it.

Comment: If u added `header("Content-type: video/mp4");` then you can echo file dir + file name in server

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624012/how-to-download-the-video-using-php-script

this example might help you